# Error in pagination with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using pagination with ajax to display my records but at the end I got these error in my console whenever I click on the button for next page.

This is the error which I get

```
  jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/ajax/products?page=2 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My controller is:

```
public function index()
{
    $hospitals = Hospital::paginate(3);
    return View::make('patientPanel/patientHospital')->with('hospitals',$hospitals);
}
 }
```

My routes are

```
 Route::get('/patientPanel/patientHospital',
         'patientHospitalController@index');
 Route::get('ajax/patienthospital',function(){
  $hospitals = Hospital::paginate(3);
 return 
View::make('/patientPanel/patientHospital')>with('hospitals',$hospitals)->render();
 });
```

And my view

```
  <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        @foreach($hospitals as $hospital)
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn content" data-
           wow-offset="50" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
          <div class="team-wrapper">
            <img src="/uploads/{{$hospital->picture }}" class="img-responsive" alt="team img 1" style="height: 270px; width: 500px">
              <div class="team-des">
                <h4>{{$hospital->name}}</h4>
                <span>Designer</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitquisque tempus ac eget diam et laoreet phasellus ut nisi id leo molest.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
      {{$hospitals->links()}}
    </div>
  </section>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     var page = ($(this).attr('href').split('page='))[1];
     getProducts(page);
  });

  function getProducts(page)
  {
    $.ajax({
       url:'ajax/patientHospital?page?page='+page
    }).done(function(data){

        $('.content').html(data);
        location.hash = page;
    });

  }
</script>
```

This is my code please tell me what I have done wrong because of which I am getting this error.

Comment: check your logs, laravel log and server log for what the 500 is caused from.

Answer (score 0):

in this a syntax error in my route resturn statement

> return 
>   View::make('/patientPanel/patientHospital')>with('hospitals',$hospitals)->render();

write as

> return 
>   View::make('/patientPanel/patientHospital')->with('hospitals',$hospitals)->render();